# I have the "Unable to locate adb" Andorid Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am starting with Android Studio, have the "unable to locate adb", so far I read that I need to go to File > Project Settings. but my Android Stuido has NO Project Setting options under the File menu.

[image: menu]

Comment: If you are using Anti-Virus, you can first check the virus chest and restore it from there. Otherwise, just go to your SDK Manager and install Android SDK Tools.

Comment: What if I already have those too?